# Swift T does not convert to T

Tags: swift, functional-programming

```
func mapGen<T>(transform:((T)->T),collection:Array<T>) -> Array<T> {

    func cat<T>(initial:Array<T>,element:T) -> Array<T> {
        var mInitial = initial;
        var telement = transform(element);
            mInitial.append(telement);
        return mInitial;
    }
    var k = collection.reduce([],cat);
    return k;
}
```

I am getting a issue trying to run this piece of code. 
I new to swift can anyone help me out ?

I am trying to write a generic map out of a reduce function it does not appear to be working.

Comment: try change `func cat<T>` to `func cat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
func mapGen<T>(transform:((T)->T),collection:Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
```

you are defining a generic type T, and in the nested function:

```
func cat<T>(initial:Array<T>,element:T) -> Array<T> {
```

you are (re)defining a new generic type with the same name, but which is actually a different type - you can even name it V or NewType, you still have the same error.

I deduct that in your case you want the nested function to use the same T type, so just do not redefine it:

```
 func cat(initial:Array<T>,element:T) -> Array<T> {
```

and it should work as expected

Comment: Thank you for the explaination

Answer (score 1):

To make the error message (which currently sounds pretty non-sensical) clearer, let's rename your type variables, so that you don't have two type variables with the same name:

```
func mapGen<T1>(transform:((T1)->T1),collection:Array<T1>) -> Array<T1> {

    func cat<T2>(initial:Array<T2>,element:T2) -> Array<T2> {
        var mInitial = initial;
        var telement = transform(element);
            mInitial.append(telement);
        return mInitial;
    }
    var k = collection.reduce([],cat);
    return k;
}
```

Now the error message becomes "T1 does not convert to T2", which makes a lot more sense. The reason that you're getting that error is the expression `transform(element)`. `element` has the type `T2`, but `transform` expects an argument of type `T1`.

Fundamentally the problem is that you're promising that `cat` can work with any given type, but in reality it can only work with values of the outer `T`, so the solution would be to simply remove the type parameter of `cat` and use the outer `T` in the types of its arguments.

Comment: Yeah I realized about 5 seconds ago, that I nested 2 ts in the second function.